Hive Always Fails at Mapreduce
I just installed hadoop 3.3.6 and hive 4.0.0 with mysql as metastore. when running create table or select * from... it runs well. But when I try to do insert or select join, hive always fails. I'm noticing that hive fails at the mapreduce task and "requires lock = true" even though I didn't create any lock.

I already gave chmod 777 permission to the warehouse directory in hdfs but it didn't solve my problem.
yarn doesn't give log when using MR execution Engine
Here's the log that I get from hive.log:
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask
No Stats for default@student1, Columns: name, gpa, age
No Stats for default@student2, Columns: nama, jurusan, hobi
Query ID = hadoop_20240923190426_36da4532-a25c-4d21-b7ec-47f18290f3dd
Total jobs = 1
java.lang.NullPointerException  at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:843)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.<init>(JobConf.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.<init>(JobConf.java:475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask.initialize(MapredLocalTask.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.main(ExecDriver.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Execution failed with exit status: 1
Obtaining error information

Task failed!
Task ID:
  Stage-4

Logs:

/tmp/hadoop/hive.log
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask

Sorry for my bad English and wrong use of tool in this forum. It's my first time asking here.
update:
here's my core-site.xml:
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/home/hadoop/tmpdata</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.server.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.server.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>

hdfs-site.xml:
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>

as for my hive-site.xml it's pretty much the same as the template hive gave. just some change for connecting to mysql metastore.
update
here's my hive-site.xml:
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
    <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</value>
    <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>hadoop</value>
    <description>user name for connecting to mysql server </description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>12345</value>
    <description>password for connecting to mysql server </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
<description>Thrift URI for the remote metastore. Used by metastore client to connect to remote metastore.</description>
</property>
</configuration>


Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, chmod 777 is wrong and dangerous. You absolutely do not want to grant write access to executable or system files to all users under any circumstances. You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably chmod 755) and learn about the Unix permissions model before you try to use it again. If this happened on a system with Internet access, check whether an intruder could have exploited this to escalate their privileges.

Please show your hive-site.xml, core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml as text with an [edit]

thanks for the advice! I'm still learning how to use hadoop, hive, spark, etc. I put my hive-site.xml on link because it's so long and pretty much the same as the template. my teacher said it has something to do with yarn, so I follow this link to setting my yarn-site,xml but it doesn't work

I tried to example job that hadoop give and it didn't work either. turns out my mapred-site.xml configuration was wrong. so I changed the mapred-site.xml to the following configuration:
<configuration> 
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
    <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
    <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
    <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}</value>
</property>
</configuration>

I was pointing HADOOP_MAPREDUCE_HOME direcly into lib folder and that's why every mapreduce job fail
